# Matching tables in python

Tags: python

I have a following problem:

I have two tables, (`txt`/`csv`), with two columns (first column position x, second column position y) and they make a pair.

T tables have to be read and the values matched: so every x-y pair in table one has to be compared to every x-y pair in table two. If there are any matches, a new table has to be created.

I already did that in `TopCat`, but need it in Python (I use Python `2.7`). However, the values aren't rounded equally and if I match them, there are no matching pairs (e.g. `1.2398` & `3.9735`, `1.239857` & `3.973522`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I don't have time for a real answer, but... [`round(number, num_digits)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to round to i.e. 4 decimal places is do: `'%0.4f' % float(1.239857)` where the output will be `1.2399`.

For your problem -- since I have plenty of time~ --, you can use/refer to:

```
def get_coordinates(infile, delimiter):
    new_list = []
    with open(infile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            x, y = [float(i) for i in line.strip().split(delimiter)]

            ## rounding happens here: 4 decimal places for x and y
            new_list.append('%0.4f,%0.4f' % (x, y))

    return new_list


## Extract x,y coordinates from input file given delimiter 
LIST1 = get_coordinates('table1.txt', ',')
LIST2 = get_coordinates('table2.txt', ',')

## New list with common coordinates between the two file
NEW_LIST = list(set(LIST1) & set(LIST2))

## print result to output file: "outfile.txt"
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for xy in NEW_LIST:
        ## write entries "x,y" -- this the default
        outfile.write('%s\n' % xy)

        ## -----------------------------------------------------
        ## by default it will be CSV, but
        ## if you want to split by tabs then
        ## comment out previous part & uncomment the following:
        ## -----------------------------------------------------

        # outfile.write('%s\n' % '\t'.join(xy.split(',')))
```

Comment: There **is** a difference though. Using `round` will also well... round the results while your solution will simply convert the floats to strings and slice them 4 digits after the dot. I'm not sure what would be the preferred option by OP

Comment: I think this method first rounds the float to 4 digit after the dot, and then converts it to a string ... since `'%0.4f' % 0.99999999999` produces `'1.0000'` not '0.9999' :)

Comment: Oh OK. Weird, I wasn't aware of that. Seems a tad unintuitive. Why would string formatting do anything else besides format a string? I wonder if it's using the same functionality as `round` and if not whether you'd always get the same results... This is quite interesting...

Comment: When I run the program, I get "ValueError" on lines: --> 204             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where); ---> 18 LIST1 = get_coordinates('table1.txt', ',  ') & ----> 9             x, y = [float(i) for i in line.strip().split('delimiter')]
in that order. The last line reads: 222.27515,  8.0208306eral for float(): 222.30777,  8.9363889
I don't understand why this is not working correctly…